# Apache logs timestamp to Date typescript

Tags: apache, date, typescript, logging

I am getting this timestamp `"18/May/2011:12:40:18 -0700"` from an Apache log and I want to convert it to a Date type. I want to extract from the timestamp the day of the month, the month, the year and the time.

When I try to create a new Date from the data showed before, I receive `Invalid data` error message from TS compiler. I think the `-0700` is the problem, so I ask for a solution, please.

Comment: I think [this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/sasanuzuya/edit?js,console) example shows the issue you're having. JavaScript can't parse that format into a date. (The -0700 is the difference to UTC). You will probably need to parse the date yourself or use a library

Comment: Although I would expect that to be a runtime error, not a TS compiler error ...

Comment: You were right dude, it works for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below shows the issue you're having. JavaScript can't parse that format into a date. (The -0700 is the difference to UTC).

```js
var dates = [];

dates.push(new Date("18/May/2011:12:40:18 -0700"));
dates.push(new Date("18/May/2011:12:40:18-0700"));
dates.push(new Date("2011-05-18:12:40:18-0700"));

dates.forEach(parsedDate => console.log(parsedDate.toString()))
```

You will probably need to parse the date yourself or use a library

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the colon between date and time. You need to replace it with a space.

```js
var timestamp = '18/May/2011:12:40:18 -0700';

var jsdate = new Date(timestamp.replace(':',' '));
```